# How to omit some parameters of structure Gin gonic

Tags: go, struct, reflection, go-gin

I have big structure with more than 50 params

```
type Application struct {
    Id                  int64   `json:"id"`
    FullName            string  `json:"fullName,omitempty"`
    ActualAddress       string  `json:"actualAddress,omitempty"`
.....
}
```

I use gin-gonic and when I return `application` I need to omit some params I've created a function which makes empty some params ([playLink](https://play.golang.org/p/n_cyxa1WW7h)) and then gin returns me correct json (without unnecessary values). I heard that reflection isn't fast operation so in our case we can use a lot of ugly if-else or switch-cases. Is there any other solutions faster than reflecting and more beautiful than if-elses?

The thing is that structure params have non-empty values, so they wont by omitted by gin. That's why I've created function to make some params empty before return

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You want to omit fields from JSON output? `,omitempty` option already does that.

Comment: @icza plz, check UPD

Comment: Are the fields you want to omit always the same? Say in your example do you always need to omit the two fields `"FullName", "ActualAddress"` from the `Application`'s json? Or do you need to keep them in some cases, and omit other fields in other cases?

Comment: @mkopriva not the same, in one case omit one set of params in other another

Comment: If your goal is just to omit those values in JSON, set the json tag to `-` for those fields.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, if you only want to zero a few fields, it's more readable to do it without a function, e.g.

```
app := Application{}

app.FullName, app.ActualAddress = "", ""
```

If you want to create a function for it, at least use variadic parameter, so it's easier to call it:

```
func zeroFields(application *Application, fields ...string) {
    // ...
}
```

So then calling it:

```
zeroFields(&app, "FullName", "ActualAddress")
```

Yes, this will have to use reflection, so it's slower than it could be, and error prone (mistyped names can only be detected at runtime). If you want to avoid using reflection, pass the address of the fields:

```
func zeroFields(ps ...*string) {
    for _, p := range ps {
        *p = ""
    }
}
```

This way you have compile-time guarantee that you type field names correctly, and that they have `string` type.

Calling it:

```
zeroFields(&application.FullName, &application.ActualAddress)
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HOehUM6Bf3b).

Comment: Omitting FullName, ActualAddress was just an example, what if we have different combinations each time? Structure is big, and combinations can be thousands

Comment: @mondayguy Please read the full answer. I proposed `zeroFields()` which takes pointers.

Comment: the thing is that we have roles in our system and I need to omit some params for each role... omited params stored in DB and can be different...Is is more clear now? Sorry for bad english

Comment: I mean that we must call the zeroFilelds function with some string array with omitting field name, because it can be thousands of combinations

Comment: Yes, and you can do that. You can pass slices to variadic functions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you want to return some values from your struct but not all of them? Perhaps a nested struct?

```
type Application struct {
  ID struct {
    ID int64 `json:"id"`
  } `json:"id"`
  Person struct {
    Fullname string `json:"Fullname"
  } `json:"person"
}
```

That should let you filter out the fields you want to use.